# overflow:auto doesn't work, does not show the scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I need to put a vertical scrollbar on each md-content (content-left & content-right). I've been trying to figure this out for several hours, but it isn't working.

This is my example code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvvodN

html:

```
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="listdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp" >
      <div layout="row" class="main">
      <div flex="50" class="left">  
        <md-content class="content-left">
        <md-list>
          <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">3 line item</md-subheader>
          <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in todos">
            <img ng-src="{{item.face}}?{{$index}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}">
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{ item.who }}</h3>
              <h4>{{ item.what }}</h4>
              <p>{{ item.notes }}</p>
            </div>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-content>
      </div>


       <div flex class="right">  
        <md-content class"content-right">
        <md-list>
          <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">3 line item</md-subheader>
          <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in todos">
            <img ng-src="{{item.face}}?{{$index}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}">
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{ item.who }}</h3>
              <h4>{{ item.what }}</h4>
              <p>{{ item.notes }}</p>
            </div>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-content>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;}
.main{
  border: 2px solid red;}
.left{
  border: 2px solid green;}
.content-left{
  overflow:auto;}
.right{
  border: 2px solid blue;}
.content-right{
  overflow: auto;}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As other people already said, you need a fixed height for `overflow` to work. In your codepen I see you have added to your body and html: `height:100%`. If your intention is to give your left and right content also 100% of the window height and scroll when not enough room, every children NEEDS the same `height:100%`

Basically if You add this

```
.content-left, .content-right, .left, .right, .layout, .listdemoBasicUsage {height:100%}
```

your `codepen` will look as I think you want.

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbbLYy)** (your right content does not work because you have two `"class="xxxxx"` in the same html tag... choose one of put classes inside just one `class`)

Edited: Maybe your project will have a header and a footer with fixed height (or more elements). If that happens you may need to change the container your now 100% parent to:

```
height:calc(100% - XXpx - YYpx);
```

(where XX are your header height and YY your footer height) then it will still works the same as you can see in this modified [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYYNPb))

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more think, Why you include .layout in the css rule? is a material class?

Comment: I edited a bit the answer so it may help you in the future

Comment: one of the many multiples children that needs the `height:100%` is: `<div layout="row" class="main layout layout-row">` I just got one of the classes of that `div`. take into account that I debug a page bsed on the html translated at tools like chrome inspector, firebug, etc. Often the html doens't look the same as it happens when you make a page with asp.net code (asp:label turning into span, etc)

Answer (score 3):

`overflow: auto;` only works in conjunction with a fixed height for the element. If the element isn't fixed height, there will never be any overflow, so the `auto` will never apply.

Consider adding a `max-height` or `height` to `.content-right` and `.content-left` to make the scrollbar show up.

Comment: Thank you your answer work but I find a example and all heights are relatives. http://triangular.oxygenna.com/#/email/inbox/mail/55f1747cbc5fa

Answer (score 1):

You need to let your containers know what the bounds are. So if you don't want to specify a height like @Aeolingamenfel said, you can do absolute positioning:

```
.content-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: True. However you approach it, you need to make sure that the element has bounds, because then its possible for overflow to happen.